# How do I iterate over every value in a key where the value is the instance of a class?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, oop

I want to iterate over every instance i stored as a value to a number stored as a key in a dictionary. Where if I were to make an account named jason, it would be assigned 1, then if I were to make a new one, it would be assigned 2. That part is already done but the iteration part is very confusing for me. Why does it only go through the first key value pair in the dictionary?

Ps: I am new to oop this is my first oop thing where i did not follow any guides so that id would actually learn. Thank you <3

```
class Bank:
  serialnum = 0
  username = ""
  email = ""
  password = ""
  bal = 0
  
  
  def __init__(self,count):
    self.serialnum = count
    self.username = input("What's your username? \n")
    self.email = input("What's your email? \n")
    self.password = input("What's your password \n")
    self.bal = input("How much balance do you have \n")

    def withdraw(money):
      self.bal= bal-money 
      print (bal)
      

global count
count = 0 #counts and is the serial num
accounts = {} #accounts dictionary

def accountcreate(): #gets called when account does not exist
  global count
  while True:
    serial = int(count)
    account = Bank(count)
    print("The serial is {}".format(count))
    count += 1
    accounts[serial] = account
    print("Your account has been created, please use the username registered. ")
    break
  accountaccess()
    
    
def accountverify(name):#if accountverify returns false, prompts the accountcreate function
  username = ""
  start = 0
  balance = 0
  if 0 in accounts: #essentially means if the first account has been made
      for key in accounts: #loops through accounts in accounts dictionary
         #sets the keys gotten and sets the un to the username attribute of every key
      
        if hasattr((accounts[key]),"username") == name:
          print("logged in as ", name, "Password is \n", 
                (getattr((accounts[key]), "password")), 
                "Account balance is ", getattr((accounts[key]), "bal"))

          action = input("What do you want to do? \n -Withdraw \n -Deposit \n -Transfer \n -Make another account \n")
          if "make" in action:
            print("Making another account... \n Please enter your credentials")
            makeaccount = accountcreate()
          
       
        else: #if username does not exist
          print("First item in list is ",(getattr((accounts[key]),"username")))
          print(accounts)
          accountask = input("Account does not exist, make a new account? Yes or No \n").lower()
          if accountask == "yes":
            makeAccount = accountcreate()
       
  else: #makes first account
    ask1 = (input("Account does not exist, would you like to make an account? Yes or No \n")).lower()
    if ask1 == "yes":
      makeAccount =  accountcreate()

def accountaccess(): #accesses account
  ask = (input("Do you want to access an account? Yes, or no. "))
  if ask == "yes":
    getname = (input("What is your username? ")).lower()
    ver = accountverify(getname) 
    loop = False
  
    
loop = True
while loop == True: #mainloop
  ask = (input("Do you want to access an account? Yes, or no. \n")).lower()
  if ask == "yes":
    getname = (input("What is your username? ")).lower()
    ver = accountverify(getname) 
    loop = False
```

[The replit link](https://replit.com/@harzche/bankPy#main.py)

It would also be helpful to know how to store the username as the name of the value since what is shown there is incredibly cryptic

[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV2S9.png), every new username registered is a new instance of the Bank class. But the for loop only goes on the first one

Comment: Please do not paste links to replits or images of code and error messages. Instead, copy and paste them directly into your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of your code that is causing the issue is

```
if hasattr((accounts[key]),"username") == name:
          print("logged in as ", name, "Password is \n", 
                (getattr((accounts[key]), "password")), 
                "Account balance is ", getattr((accounts[key]), "bal"))
```

The return from `hasattr` is a `boolean` and cannot be compared to `name`.

Try changing it too

```
if hasattr(accounts[key],"username"):
    if accounts[key].username == name:
        ....
```

Also your use of `getattr()` is incorrect and unnecessary since you can simply access those attributes directly.

For example:

```
account = accounts[key]
print(account.username)
print(account.password)
print(account.bal)
```

with all of that in mind your `accountsverify` function should look more like this:

```
def accountverify(name):
  start = 0
  balance = 0
  if 0 in accounts:
      for key in accounts:  
        account = accounts[key]
        if account.username == name:
          print(f"logged in as {name} Password is \n {account.password} \n Account balance is {account.bal}")

          action = input("What do you want to do? \n -Withdraw \n -Deposit \n -Transfer \n -Make another account \n")
          if "make" in action:
            print("Making another account... \n Please enter your credentials")
            makeaccount = accountcreate()
          
       
        else: #if username does not exist
          print("First item in list is ",account.username)
          print(accounts)
          accountask = input("Account does not exist, make a new account? Yes or No \n").lower()
          if accountask == "yes":
            makeAccount = accountcreate()
```

As far as making the `Bank` class print the accounts name you just need to overwrite the `__str__` method.

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Then I can use account.bal to for example, access the balance of the iterated account?

Comment: @shit yes i do that in the example at the end of the print statement...  at the end of the line

Comment: I tried ur code, didnt work then I copy pasted it and also didnt work, it did the same thing. Is there something wrong with what I did  

[link](https://replit.com/@harzche/bankPy#main.py)

Comment: @shit  Well right away I can tell you that your `__str__` is at the wrong indentation...  look at my example again.... as for the rest of it... what error are you getting?  When I run it it seems to work

Comment: Can i message you on discord xd im bad at using stackoverflow rn

Comment: the error im getting is that i keep getting the error, the account does not exist despite the account already existing

Comment: try making 2 or 3 accounts then try to access the 2nd, 3rd account

Comment: @shit  That isn't working because of the way you are iterating through each item.  what is your discord username?

Comment: my discord is harzche#1128, I also messaged on the Python discord for help but unfortunately no one replied. Thank you so much.

Comment: This will probably be easier [repl](https://replit.com/join/julozqgokb-alexpdev)